# Where do I have to use the & operator in PHP?

Tags: java, php

A few years ago I used to work with PHP and there've been many changes in PHP, especially on the OOP part.

Back then it was necessary to use the `&` operator at several places, especially when working with object instances (OOP was very rudimentary then) to avoid copying object instances.

With PHP 5.2 there seems to be a lot of improvement compared to 4.0 and I'm a little bit confused.

When do I have to use the `&` operator in PHP to avoid any unpleasant surprises from a Java programmer's perspective?

Examples:

```
$a = (&)new MyClass();    //Necessary?

function factoryMethod() {
  $a = (&)new MyClass();  //Necessary?
  return (&) $a;          //Necessary?
}

// Other cases?!
```

**EDIT:** By chance my examples don't need the `&` operator at all. But where would I need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it short: nowhere in your examples.

In case we're dealing with `objects` you do not have to use the [reference operator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) at all.

If you're dealing with other datatypes the most common reference operations are:

### [Passing by Reference](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
```

### [Returning References](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

```
class foo {
    public $value = 42;

    public function &getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->getValue(); // $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
$obj->value = 2;
echo $myValue; // prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2.
```

### [Looping with `foreach`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
```

Be careful as the last `unset()`-call is important if your code uses `$value` again downstream.

Whereas the first case (passing by reference) is much more common than the second case, e.g. especially when dealing with arrays:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
function modifyArray(&$data)
{
    unset($data[1]);
}
modifyArrax($array);
// $array = array(0 => 1, 2 => 3, 3 => 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically don't ever use the `&` operator unless you need it (and try not to *need* it). None of your examples need it.

All objects in PHP are passed by reference. If you do this:

```
$arr = range(1,4);
func($arr);

function func($arr) {
  unset($arr[3]);
}
```

it will not modify the original array but change it to this:

```
function func(&$arr) {
  unset($arr[3]);
}
```

and it will. Whereas with objects:

```
class A { public $b; }

$a = new A;
$a->b = 3;
func($a);
echo $a->b; // 5

function func($a) {
  $a->b = 5;
}
```

Everything else is copy-on-write.

So the two circumstances where you will sometimes use the `&` operator are:

1. On function arguments to pass by reference a non-object; and
2. In a loop to modify the array.

An example of (2) is:

```
$arr = range(1,4);
foreach ($arr as &$v) {
  $v += 10;
}
```

Without the `&` `$arr` wouldn't be modified.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5, you don't need to use the & operator in any of the places you've shown them in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the correct answer...
But you could take a look at the php5 manual about oop.
It can be found here: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Yes, I saw that and I noticed that the & operator is not used. That's why I asked to get some more details about when and when not it should be used.